# Error 80070005 when trying to connect to Bluetooth LE device in Metro App

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing cross-platform app that uses Bluetooth Low Energy technology to connect to Polar H7 heart rate monitor. I have problems only with Windows 8 application.

To learn LE device connection possibilities I'm trying to launch Bluetooth Low Energy Health Profiles sample

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-LE-Metro-sample-a2ba1b5b

So, my actions:

1. First of all I downloaded source code of this sample and compiled it. I have some problems with it. I live in Moscow, Russia and my time is UTC+4. When I tried to build this sample I had an error "DriverVer set to incorrect date (postdated DriverVer not allowed)". I had to change the time zone in my system and then build was successful.
2. Then I added Package.cer to my certificate storage and installed the driver.
3. I opened Device Metadata Authoring wizard and made the device-metadata package with these parameters:

   Package Name: Microsoft.SDKSamples.BluetoothLEHealthProfiles.JS
   Publisher: CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
   BluetoothLEHealthProfiles.HealthDevicesApp

   Dublicated data in privileged data section and set Access Custom Driver to "true"

   Hardware ID's:
     BTHLEDevice{0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_LOCALMFG&000f
     BTHLE\Dev_fe65d3a17796
     BTHLEDevice{0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}

   Model name: Heart Rate Service
   Manufacturer: Microsoft
   Category: Health.HeartRate
4. Then I installed copied this metadata information to the system and finally connected my device
5. I've created StoreManifest.xml file and pasted my ExperienceID there
6. I've built Metro App Sample and received error 80070005 when trying to execute

   deviceFactory.getDeviceFromIdAsync(devices[0].id, function (device) {
       ...
   }

I'm trying to connect to LE device during several days but the result is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have exactly the same issue and the documentation is...lacking

Comment: It normally points to permission errors accessing the driver. For the metadata did you follow the wizard? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454213(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just not read all the manual and didn't changed properties for store package.